# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython2.7

Tags: python, linux, mysql-python

I'm trying to install MySQLdb with Python 2.7. The error I'm getting looks like this:

```
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,3,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.3 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/opt/python2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -L/usr/lib64/mysql -L. -lmysqlclient_r -lz -lpthread -lcrypt -lnsl -lm -lpthread -lmygcc -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython2.7
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Clearly, it can't find Python 2.7. Looking in `/usr/bin` I see:

```
python*
python2@
python2.4*
python2.7@
```

What does the `@` symbol mean? Can anyone advise a remedy to the error?

Comment: you probably need the `python-dev` package (not related with the @)

Comment: Don't think you want the Python binary.  Looks like you need the Python .o files since this is linking.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be on serverfault?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It can't find the Python library, not the executable. Run `locate libpython2.7.a` to see where your Python library is located, and add it to the library path (e.g. if it is in `/opt/python2.7/lib`, you want to call `LDFLAGS="-L/opt/python2.7/lib" make`).

The `@` symbol means the file is a symbolic link; `*` means it's executable (these are produced by [`ls -F`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ls), which you might have as an alias).

Comment: Thanks for the response Petr, that's very informative. The two locations I have after running locate are:

/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/config/
/usr/src/python2.7/Python-2.7.2/

After running LDFLAGS="-L/[path]" on both of these locations I'm still getting the same error. There's no discernible change in /usr/bin either.

Comment: Hmm... Are you maybe running it as a command? You shouldn't, it's setting an environment variable, as in `LDFLAGS="-L/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/config/" ./configure` or `LDFLAGS="-L/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/config/" make` (I don't know how MySQLdb is built exactly)

Comment: Ah, perfect! Thank you, sorry for my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 9):

The above solution didn't quite do it for me as I was using pip to install mysql-python, but was definitely a big push in the right direction. For the benefit of anyone who lands here from Google in the same situation as me, my solution was to symlink `libpython2.7.a` from the python installation directory to the lib dir:

> `ln -s /opt/python2.7.1/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a`
>
> `/usr/local/lib/`

`pip install mysql-python` worked without any issues afterwards.

Comment: This worked for me as well on CentOS 6.3.  I tried adding `/opt/python2.7.1/lib/python2.7/config` to `/etc/ld.so.con.d/python2.7.conf` and running `sudo ldconfig`, but Linux isn't adding the `.a` file to its library list, i.e. ld.so.cache.  Maybe this is by design.  Symlinking was the solution.

Comment: After hours of gcc errors I finally found this solution. This worked perfectly in CentOS 6.5. I used ln -s /opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a /usr/local/lib/

Comment: above comment just saved my day