# /usr/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lpython2.7

Tags: python, linux, gcc, compilation

While installing `pyscard.py` I get this error:

```
gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN/../lib -g -L/home/builder/jenkins/workspace/Python_Masters/ARCH/x86_64/label/Linux/core/lib build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/smartcard/scard/helpers.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/smartcard/scard/winscarddll.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/smartcard/scard/scard_wrap.o -L/home/builder/jenkins/workspace/Python_Masters/ARCH/x86_64/label/Linux/core/lib -lpython2.7 -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/smartcard/scard/_scard.so
/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lpython2.7
/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lpython2.7
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400272/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lpython2-7) with the same problem; I can't get it to work, i still get the same result and i don't really know what to make of the ./configure or make after the path. Can anyone clarify this for me, please?

Comment: You found *which* post, sorry? And more information than "I can't get it work" would be helpful.

Comment: fixed it ... i think, sorry, was in abit of a hurry

Comment: Generally it means you need to have the ``python-dev`` package installed and do not.