# Pip install errored out with exit status 1

Tags: python, path, pip, package, fedora

I tried to install a python package (rebound) using pip install but I got the error message I added **below**. I use fedora 31 if that is helpful.

I asked the creator of the package about this but he said that this seems to be general pip problem instead of a problem with his package. https://github.com/hannorein/rebound/issues/427

There were some other people having similar issues [/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400272/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lpython2-7/8400446#8400446?newreg=bdb25c32d9594334bf73d20d4bc0510a)

They recommended installing the python-dev-tools which didn't help me. One comment said to find where the file libpython3.7.a is (he said to find libpython2.7.a but my version is 3.7.6) and then use this command:

```
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib" make
```

which doesn't work and instead returns this message:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

He said this might work too:

```
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib" ./configure
```

But that didn't work too and returned:

```
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

/usr/local/lib is where my libpython3.7.a file is btw.

I tried using pip3 install, python -m pip install, python3 -m pip install etc. None of them worked. Also all of my packages are up to date.

I hope you understand my problem. Thank you all in advance.

Tobias

Command

```
pip install rebound
```

Error

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-r4o30ca2/rebound/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-r4o30ca2/rebound/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-vgescvxa/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/tobias/.local/include/python3.7m/rebound
     cwd: /tmp/pip-install-r4o30ca2/rebound/
Complete output (123 lines):
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/rebound
copying rebound/widget.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/rebound
copying rebound/units.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/rebound
copying rebound/tools.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/rebound
copying rebound/simulationarchive.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/rebound
copying rebound/simulation.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/rebound
copying rebound/plotting.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/rebound
copying rebound/particle.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/rebound
copying rebound/interruptible_pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/rebound
copying rebound/horizons.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/rebound
copying rebound/data.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/rebound
copying rebound/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/rebound
copying rebound/rebound.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/rebound
running build_ext
building 'librebound' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DLIBREBOUND -Isrc -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/rebound.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/rebound.o -fstrict-aliasing -O3 -std=c99 -Wno-unknown-pragmas -DGITHASH=d15889dce6327b47ace8111b0b376361aba81ff9 -DLIBREBOUND -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DLIBREBOUND -Isrc -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/integrator_ias15.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/integrator_ias15.o -fstrict-aliasing -O3 -std=c99 -Wno-unknown-pragmas -DGITHASH=d15889dce6327b47ace8111b0b376361aba81ff9 -DLIBREBOUND -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DLIBREBOUND -Isrc -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/integrator_whfast.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/integrator_whfast.o -fstrict-aliasing -O3 -std=c99 -Wno-unknown-pragmas -DGITHASH=d15889dce6327b47ace8111b0b376361aba81ff9 -DLIBREBOUND -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC
src/integrator_whfast.c: In function ‘reb_integrator_whfast_init’:
src/integrator_whfast.c:773:32: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘unsigned int’ and ‘int’ [-Wsign-compare]
  773 |     if (ri_whfast->allocated_N != N){
      |                                ^~
src/integrator_whfast.c: In function ‘reb_integrator_whfast_part2’:
src/integrator_whfast.c:1056:44: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘unsigned int’ and ‘int’ [-Wsign-compare]
 1056 |             if (ri_whfast->allocated_Ntemp != N){
      |                                            ^~
src/integrator_whfast.c:1070:36: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘unsigned int’ and ‘int’ [-Wsign-compare]
 1070 |             for (unsigned int i=1;i<N;i++){
      |                                    ^
src/integrator_whfast.c:1082:36: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘unsigned int’ and ‘int’ [-Wsign-compare]
 1082 |             for (unsigned int i=1;i<N;i++){
      |                                    ^
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DLIBREBOUND -Isrc -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/integrator_saba.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/integrator_saba.o -fstrict-aliasing -O3 -std=c99 -Wno-unknown-pragmas -DGITHASH=d15889dce6327b47ace8111b0b376361aba81ff9 -DLIBREBOUND -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC
src/integrator_saba.c: In function ‘reb_saba_corrector_step’:
src/integrator_saba.c:155:44: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘unsigned int’ and ‘int’ [-Wsign-compare]
  155 |             if (ri_whfast->allocated_Ntemp != N){
      |                                            ^~
src/integrator_saba.c:171:36: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘unsigned int’ and ‘int’ [-Wsign-compare]
  171 |             for (unsigned int i=1;i<N;i++){
      |                                    ^
src/integrator_saba.c:183:36: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘unsigned int’ and ‘int’ [-Wsign-compare]
  183 |             for (unsigned int i=1;i<N;i++){
      |                                    ^
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DLIBREBOUND -Isrc -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/integrator_mercurius.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/integrator_mercurius.o -fstrict-aliasing -O3 -std=c99 -Wno-unknown-pragmas -DGITHASH=d15889dce6327b47ace8111b0b376361aba81ff9 -DLIBREBOUND -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC
src/integrator_mercurius.c: In function ‘reb_mercurius_encounter_step’:
src/integrator_mercurius.c:276:29: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘unsigned int’ and ‘int’ [-Wsign-compare]
  276 |     for (unsigned int i=0; i<r->N; i++){
      |                             ^
src/integrator_mercurius.c:281:37: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘unsigned int’ and ‘int’ [-Wsign-compare]
  281 |             if (r->N_active==-1 || i<r->N_active){
      |                                     ^
src/integrator_mercurius.c: In function ‘reb_integrator_mercurius_part1’:
src/integrator_mercurius.c:359:30: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘unsigned int’ and ‘int’ [-Wsign-compare]
  359 |     if (rim->dcrit_allocatedN<N){
      |                              ^
src/integrator_mercurius.c:369:24: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘unsigned int’ and ‘int’ [-Wsign-compare]
  369 |     if (rim->allocatedN<N){
      |                        ^
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DLIBREBOUND -Isrc -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/integrator_eos.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/integrator_eos.o -fstrict-aliasing -O3 -std=c99 -Wno-unknown-pragmas -DGITHASH=d15889dce6327b47ace8111b0b376361aba81ff9 -DLIBREBOUND -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC
src/integrator_eos.c: In function ‘reb_integrator_eos_drift_shell1’:
src/integrator_eos.c:359:19: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘unsigned int’ [-Wsign-compare]
  359 |     for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
      |                   ^
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DLIBREBOUND -Isrc -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/integrator_leapfrog.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/integrator_leapfrog.o -fstrict-aliasing -O3 -std=c99 -Wno-unknown-pragmas -DGITHASH=d15889dce6327b47ace8111b0b376361aba81ff9 -DLIBREBOUND -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DLIBREBOUND -Isrc -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/integrator_janus.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/integrator_janus.o -fstrict-aliasing -O3 -std=c99 -Wno-unknown-pragmas -DGITHASH=d15889dce6327b47ace8111b0b376361aba81ff9 -DLIBREBOUND -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC
src/integrator_janus.c: In function ‘reb_integrator_janus_synchronize’:
src/integrator_janus.c:259:32: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘unsigned int’ and ‘int’ [-Wsign-compare]
  259 |     if (r->ri_janus.allocated_N==r->N){
      |                                ^~
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DLIBREBOUND -Isrc -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/integrator_sei.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/integrator_sei.o -fstrict-aliasing -O3 -std=c99 -Wno-unknown-pragmas -DGITHASH=d15889dce6327b47ace8111b0b376361aba81ff9 -DLIBREBOUND -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DLIBREBOUND -Isrc -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/integrator.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/integrator.o -fstrict-aliasing -O3 -std=c99 -Wno-unknown-pragmas -DGITHASH=d15889dce6327b47ace8111b0b376361aba81ff9 -DLIBREBOUND -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC
src/integrator.c: In function ‘reb_update_acceleration’:
src/integrator.c:183:20: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘unsigned int’ [-Wsign-compare]
  183 |             if(r->N>r->ri_mercurius.allocatedN_additionalforces){
      |                    ^
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DLIBREBOUND -Isrc -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/gravity.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/gravity.o -fstrict-aliasing -O3 -std=c99 -Wno-unknown-pragmas -DGITHASH=d15889dce6327b47ace8111b0b376361aba81ff9 -DLIBREBOUND -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DLIBREBOUND -Isrc -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/boundary.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/boundary.o -fstrict-aliasing -O3 -std=c99 -Wno-unknown-pragmas -DGITHASH=d15889dce6327b47ace8111b0b376361aba81ff9 -DLIBREBOUND -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DLIBREBOUND -Isrc -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/display.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/display.o -fstrict-aliasing -O3 -std=c99 -Wno-unknown-pragmas -DGITHASH=d15889dce6327b47ace8111b0b376361aba81ff9 -DLIBREBOUND -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC
src/display.c: In function ‘reb_display_copy_data’:
src/display.c:1083:13: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wsign-compare]
 1083 |     if (r->N>data->allocated_N){
      |             ^
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DLIBREBOUND -Isrc -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/collision.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/collision.o -fstrict-aliasing -O3 -std=c99 -Wno-unknown-pragmas -DGITHASH=d15889dce6327b47ace8111b0b376361aba81ff9 -DLIBREBOUND -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC
src/collision.c: In function ‘reb_collision_search’:
src/collision.c:188:25: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
  188 |                         if (rmin2_ab>rsum*rsum) continue;
      |                         ^~
src/collision.c:191:7: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘if’
  191 |       if (r->collisions_allocatedN<=collisions_N){
      |       ^~
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DLIBREBOUND -Isrc -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/tools.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/tools.o -fstrict-aliasing -O3 -std=c99 -Wno-unknown-pragmas -DGITHASH=d15889dce6327b47ace8111b0b376361aba81ff9 -DLIBREBOUND -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DLIBREBOUND -Isrc -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/derivatives.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/derivatives.o -fstrict-aliasing -O3 -std=c99 -Wno-unknown-pragmas -DGITHASH=d15889dce6327b47ace8111b0b376361aba81ff9 -DLIBREBOUND -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DLIBREBOUND -Isrc -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/tree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/tree.o -fstrict-aliasing -O3 -std=c99 -Wno-unknown-pragmas -DGITHASH=d15889dce6327b47ace8111b0b376361aba81ff9 -DLIBREBOUND -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DLIBREBOUND -Isrc -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/particle.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/particle.o -fstrict-aliasing -O3 -std=c99 -Wno-unknown-pragmas -DGITHASH=d15889dce6327b47ace8111b0b376361aba81ff9 -DLIBREBOUND -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC
src/particle.c: In function ‘reb_remove’:
src/particle.c:227:27: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘unsigned int’ [-Wsign-compare]
  227 |             for (int i=0;i<rim->encounterN;i++){
      |                           ^
src/particle.c:235:22: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘unsigned int’ [-Wsign-compare]
  235 |             if (index<rim->encounterNactive){
      |                      ^
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DLIBREBOUND -Isrc -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/binarydiff.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/binarydiff.o -fstrict-aliasing -O3 -std=c99 -Wno-unknown-pragmas -DGITHASH=d15889dce6327b47ace8111b0b376361aba81ff9 -DLIBREBOUND -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DLIBREBOUND -Isrc -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/output.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/output.o -fstrict-aliasing -O3 -std=c99 -Wno-unknown-pragmas -DGITHASH=d15889dce6327b47ace8111b0b376361aba81ff9 -DLIBREBOUND -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DLIBREBOUND -Isrc -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/input.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/input.o -fstrict-aliasing -O3 -std=c99 -Wno-unknown-pragmas -DGITHASH=d15889dce6327b47ace8111b0b376361aba81ff9 -DLIBREBOUND -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DLIBREBOUND -Isrc -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/simulationarchive.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/simulationarchive.o -fstrict-aliasing -O3 -std=c99 -Wno-unknown-pragmas -DGITHASH=d15889dce6327b47ace8111b0b376361aba81ff9 -DLIBREBOUND -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DLIBREBOUND -Isrc -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/transformations.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/transformations.o -fstrict-aliasing -O3 -std=c99 -Wno-unknown-pragmas -DGITHASH=d15889dce6327b47ace8111b0b376361aba81ff9 -DLIBREBOUND -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC
src/transformations.c: In function ‘reb_transformations_whds_to_inertial_posvel’:
src/transformations.c:301:19: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘unsigned int’ [-Wsign-compare]
  301 |     for (int i=1;i<N;i++){
      |                   ^
gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,now -g build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/rebound.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/integrator_ias15.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/integrator_whfast.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/integrator_saba.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/integrator_mercurius.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/integrator_eos.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/integrator_leapfrog.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/integrator_janus.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/integrator_sei.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/integrator.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/gravity.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/boundary.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/display.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/collision.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/tools.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/derivatives.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/tree.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/particle.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/binarydiff.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/output.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/input.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/simulationarchive.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/transformations.o -L/usr/lib64 -lpython3.7m -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/librebound.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.7m
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-r4o30ca2/rebound/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-r4o30ca2/rebound/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-vgescvxa/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/tobias/.local/include/python3.7m/rebound Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Do you have `libpython3.7m.so`?

Comment: Yes but it's in a different folder. The path is /usr/lib64/libpython3.7m.so.1.0

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved now. I had to install python3-devel and gsl-devel. Credits to reddit user awegge